# Help identify this oak tree

Tags: identification, trees

This is from a tree growing in central WA state, but since it's in a yard, it could be from anywhere.  The small seeds look very much like acorns, so it appears to be an oak of some kind.  But what kind?

The leaves are about 4.5 - 5 inches long, at the longest, and the acorns are tiny.  The tree was tall, at least 50 ft, and the owners said it grew very fast: they pointed out a branch that was several feet long and said that was all from this year.  They'd like to know what kind of tree it is.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a Live Oak or a Mexican White Oak.  Hummm....out of it's normal habitat being in Washington.

Comment: @stormy When a tree is planted in a yard, out of normal habitat is the norm.  That gives me some clues at least.

Comment: Oh I'll be watching for the answers...there are some freakin' genius plant people on this site...

Answer (score 2):

Japanese Evergreen oak, or Japanese Red Oak *(Quercus acuta)*

Informative link (including the *potential* distribution map #2 shown below): [Fact Sheet from US Forest Service](http://hort.ufl.edu/trees/QUEACUA.pdf)

Another informative link: [Oaks of the World](http://oaks.of.the.world.free.fr/quercus_acuta.htm)

[image]

See the distribution maps online:

ACTUAL DISTRIBUTION:
[image]

POTENTIAL DISTRIBUTION:
[image]